# Spark 3.1.1 throws compilation error in generated.java file

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

we are using spark 3.1.1 with java, in that i saw compilation error while processing empty dataset. error is,

```
ERROR org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.codegen.CodeGenerator: failed to compile: org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 29, Column 133: IDENTIFIER expected instead of '['
org.codehaus.commons.compiler.CompileException: File 'generated.java', Line 29, Column 133: IDENTIFIER expected instead of '['
    at org.codehaus.janino.TokenStreamImpl.read(TokenStreamImpl.java:196)
    at org.codehaus.janino.Parser.read(Parser.java:3705)


----
----
----
WARN org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec: Whole-stage codegen disabled for plan (id=30):
```

In some scenarios, we got empty dataset as follows,

```
+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|col1              |col2               |col3              |
+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
+------------------+-------------------+------------------+
```

if we try to process this dataset or dataset.show(false); throws this compilation error. But application is working fine. To maintain error free console we need to fix this one.
I tried 2 approaches,

First Approach,

Try to add null/empty array (depends on the column datatype) while creating dataset
like this,

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
dataset.withColumn("col1",
            when(col(col1.subElement).isNotNull(), col("col1")).otherwise(result));
```

In our case, col1 is proto field, in that we have multiple elements. this is one of them. subElement:[10,20,30]

SO i try to pass empty array if it doest't have any data. In that i got error as,

```
[main] WARN org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.package - Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields'.
```

if we set maxToStringFields, cause performance issue. So i did't go this way.

Second Approach,

Try by adding null check while processing this dataset. like this,

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
dataset.withColumn(("col1"),
            when(col(col1.subElement).isNull(), result).otherwise(explode(col(col1.subElement))));
```

Here, issue is we need to explode col1.subElement to many rows as it has array of elements. But i can't do null check on this. got error like below,

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Generators are not supported when it's nested in expressions, but got: CASE WHEN (col1.subElement AS `subElement` IS NULL) THEN NULL ELSE explode(col1.subElement AS `subElement`) END
```

Is there any possible way to fix this issue?